# Permission denied when geolocating inside Messenger webview

Tags: facebook, webview, messenger

I'm getting error `PERMISSION_DENIED` when using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` inside a Messenger Webview.

Is it plainly impossible to do what I want inside Messenger or is there something I must configure before?

Comment: Correct. It is impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that access to geolocation inside a Messenger Webview is really not possible.

But I found out that it's possible to send a Quick Reply prompting the user to share his location.

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for IOS App Messenger but seems that have problems with Android